# best way to get search results from google

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I am working on my assignment , in which I need to display the search results based on 3 search engine results(for ex: google,yahoo and bing). For this I made a search text box and that string posted to action method

My question is can we invoke the google.com in post action method passing this string and get the top 3 urls from that result page  or do we need to use scripting on the view page.

Once i get the urls i want to save in a list type model object and display the urls in another or same page.

Kindly provide some inputs to get this done in a best way.

Thanks,

Michaeld

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=hello

Comment: Google protects it's data like it was gold, so good luck with that. You would at the least need to use the serverside to even get access, and then figure out a way around all the dynamic stuff. Would probably be easier to use the search API.

Comment: what i found is ,if i use google api i can use only one search results , for suppose if i want to merge the urls with those from yahoo ,how can i acheive this ?